# How can I override OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) method using a column model?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have column, columnA, and columnB models. I am trying to override the" protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)" method and trying to implement backing fields.

```
public class Column<TKey> : AuditableModel<TKey>
    where TKey: IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Settings Settings {get;,set;} = new Settings();
}

public class ColumnA : Column<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public class ColumnB : Column<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    { 
        modelBuilder.Entity<ColumnA>()
            .Property(x => x.Settings)

        modelBuilder.Entity<ColumnB>()
            .Property(x => x.Settings)
```

}

How can I use a "Column" type for backing fields instead of doing this separately for a ColumnA and columnB (on a modelCreating method)?

Comment: Maybe look at `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` classes, and then register them in `OnModelCreating(...)` with `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);`.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Would you please give me an example on how to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I do it with my EF projects. This is with a simple example of a `Car` model, adapt it to fit your needs.

```
public class Car {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class CarConfiguration :
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Car> {
    public void Configure(
        EntityTypeBuilder<Car> builder) {
        builder.ToTable("Cars").HasKey(
            t => t.Id);

        builder.Property(
            p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class MyContext :
    DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        var assembly = typeof(MyContext).Assembly;

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);
    }
}
```

You can read up [more on it here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api).

Comment: Glad it helped. This is much easier in 2.0+ when they brought back the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` configurations. Before that you had to do it the way you were doing it, and that got complicated real fast depending on the size and amount of models.

Comment: So true. They make it much easier now.